# Como formatar data e hora do Mysql para o formato brasileiro em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Minhas duas dúvidas são as seguintes:

1) Quando eu recupero a data e hora (`datetime`) do banco vem nesse formato (de exemplo):

> 2016-11-12 11:19:34

Mas eu quero mostrá-la da seguinte maneira:

> 11:19:34 12/11/2016

Como fazer isso?

2) Como eu pego a data e hora em PHP, para inserir no banco de dados com esse formato:

> 2016-11-12 11:19:34

Comment: Certamente já foi respondida em uma destas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%5Bphp%5D+formatar+data

Comment: Em resumo, direto no MySQL é `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(seu_campo_data,'%d/%m/%Y') AS data_formatada FROM sua_tabela`. Versão PHP tem um monte de resposta no site, conforme link indicado pelo @Maniero.

Comment: Use o [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) na sua *query* em PHP que irá resolver o segundo problema. O *now* já vai retornar o momento atual, totalmente compreensível para o MySQL.